# use a shortcut key to jump to a "settings page"(AIR desktop)

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder

When my video is playing I want to be able to use a shortcut key to jump to a "settings page"(AIR desktop). How should I go about this.
[The video is using stagevideo class in as file and link to master mxml.file]
At the moment I am using different packages (for the "settings page") linked to my master mxml file. However when I run it, the "settings page" overlay with my video, I do not know to make it jump to another window by using a shortcut key, like say F1 key. It's there anything I miss ?

Hope someone can help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere, you need to add an event listener to the stage that will listen for `KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP`. In that event, you verify the key that is being pressed and if it is the hotkey, you send the user to a different page.

```
stage.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, settingsHotkeyHandler );

function settingsHotkeyHandler( e:KeyboardEvent ):void {
    if ( e.charCode == Keyboard.F1 ) {
        // send user here
    }
}
```

Don't forget to remove the event listener when you leave the video page. It could cause a memory issue if you don't

Comment: sorry,@Josh I think that is not the one I look for. I would like to know how to link the video page into setting page, after finish custom the setting link back again to video page by using keyboardEvent?
May I know how to link them together in same window?
which type of method and class should I use to link them together? 
Please help me on this issue.                                                                  thank you.

Comment: That really is not something anyone here can help you with. That is something entirely dependent on your codebase and how you are building your project.